# Detect when input focuses

Tags: javascript

***Sorry if this has already been asked, but all the results I've found use jQuery.***

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    var nameBox = document.getElementById('name');

    if(nameBox == document.activeElement) {
        console.log('name element focused')
    }
</script>
```

But, nothing gets logged to the console when I click on the input. What am I doing wrong? (I would like to do this without jQuery)

Comment: Use [element.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).

Comment: @Rajesh — The question is not tagged jQuery and clearly indicates in the first line that a jQuery solution is not desired.

Comment: My apologies. Missed that. Would find relevant link and share it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you are detecting if the element is active during the script's run, so you get false. After it you don't have any detectors. So you need to use `addEventListener()` function and add handler for `focus` event. It will fire when element is focused.

```js
document.getElementById('inp').addEventListener('focus', function(){
  console.log('Focused');
});
```

```html
<input id="inp" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I assume that .addEventListener('blur') would search for un-focusing the element, then.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing if the element is focused **now** instead setting up an event listener to do something **when** it gains the focus.

```
function your_function(event) {
    console.log('name element focused')
}

nameBox.addEventListener("focus", your_function);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways you can do this:

### 1. onFocus:

```js
function focused(element) {
  element.style.background = "gold";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="focused(this)">
<input type="text" onfocus="focused(this)">
```

---

### 2. addEventListener

```js
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('focus', function(element){
        document.activeElement.style.background="gold"
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
```

---

### 3. Jquery focus:

```js
$(function(){
$( "input" ).focus(function(e) {
  $(this).css( "background", "gold" );
});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
```